# iPhone|UIWebView: tabbed browsing by using NSArray?

Tags: iphone, arrays, uiwebview

I want to code a small tabbed browser just for the fun. However I'm not sure how the tabbed thing works.

So this might be a noobish question:

can I store a current webView in an array? using: [array addObject:webView];

and if yes how do I load it into the webView again? maybe using: webView = [array objetAtIndex:anIndex]; will it appear instantly?

and is it possible to store the webView in and NSDictionary as value? (would be much easier to retrieve)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store anything you want in an array (or dictionary). So assuming youll have n WebViews for n tabs, (this might take up a lot o f memory, i dont know never tried  it), when user clicks on a tab, you can do something like

```
[activeWebView removeFromSuperView]
activeWebView=[webViewArray objectAtIndex:tabIndex];
//then add the active web view to the view controller
```

Comment: I tried that just now. [mainDrowser.webView removeFromSuperview];
 mainDrowser.webView = [mainDrowser.arrayForTest objectAtIndex:0];
 [mainDrowser.view addSubview:mainDrowser.webView];
 NSLog(@"arrayForTest2: %@", mainDrowser.arrayForTest);

but the "saved" data didn't show up in the webView (only the current page)

btw. this is what is in my array
<UIWebView: 0xd2e090; frame = (0 0; 320 460); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xd2b5a0>>

Comment: it looks likes the content won't be saved in the array :( only the properties of the view.